# Prevent SSH user from executing any command line

Tags: ssh, security, login, account-restrictions

I want to know if there is any way to prevent user from executing any command line (even some simple one like `ls -la`, uptime...)
I tried some ways like delete user's bash file but it didn't work.

All users can login to the server using their own SSH key created by an admin user. This server is for authentication only so I don't want to give users permission to execute any command. What I want to get is: User can login to server and stay there, can't do anything else.

Comment: Don't allow them to login?

Comment: All user can login to server using their own SSH key created by admin user. Actually, this server is for authentication only so i don't want to give user permission to execute any command.

Comment: So use a `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config`.

Comment: Set their shell to be /bin/false

Comment: So users are able to login but they cannot execute any commands? Setting users' shell to /bin/false would exit immediatly after logging in,is that what you want?

Comment: @FrontENG Hello, what i want to get is: User can login to server and stay there, can't do anything else.

Comment: I have the feeling your approach might not be the best solution to your actual problem. What is your challenge, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What **is** the user allowed to do?

Comment: "User can login to server and stay there, can't do anything else."  **Why?** You could set the shell to `/bin/cat`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to change the user shell?

```
chsh -s /bin/true username
```

It's quite common for services that does not require a shell, e.g VsFTP

Comment: Note that the question has been clarified in comments since it was originally posted. Your answer does not apply to SSH.

Answer (score -3):

You could change the login shell to nologin:

```
~# chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin
```

To list the shells:

```
~# chsh -l
```

But, Reading your comment, you wish to allow access and deny any executable. What you could do is removing the 'other s' execute bit from the binary's in `/usr/bin` directory. I have test it with `uptime` using the following:

```
~# chmod o-x /usr/bin/uptime
```

Then, with a regular user you get

```
user@laptop ~$ uptime
bash: /usr/bin/uptime: Permission denied
```

To undo the change:

```
 ~# chmod o+x /usr/bin/uptime
```

To find your the destination of the executable, for example `ls`, you will use the command `which`:

```
user@laptop ~$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

And to find `which` is `which`:

```
~$ which which
```

To find more about Linux directory consult the man page hier:

```
~$ man hier
   hier - description of the file system hierarchy
```

EDIT:

This might miss up your system (or not, I do it to deny user's from switching by the command `su`), Using ACL permissions (Control list), you will add each user with his/her specif permission. For Example, deny *user1* from using `uptime`:

```
# setfacl -m u:user1:--- uptime
```

You could do it recursively but on your own risk.
And watch for updates, the might restore the original permissions.

Answer (score -4):

I would use `chmod` to achieve this.

For example, if you wanted to revoke read, write and execute permissions from a user you could do the following:

```
sudo chmod 770 <filehere>
```

A break down of what this actually does can be found below:

```
1st Determines the permissions in which the owner of the file has
7 = rwx (Read-Write-Execute)

2nd Determines the permissions in which the owner's group has
7 = rwx (Read-Write-Execute)

3rd Determines the permissions in which everyone else has
0 = --- (No permissions)
```

Here is a way of restricting "everyone else" from reading, writing and executing `/bin/cat`

```
sudo chmod 770 /bin/cat
```

You can verify your changes by executing `ls -la /bin/cat`

Comment: An explanation regarding downvoting my answer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is terrible advice and a completely wrong answer.  `chmod <mode> <file>` changes permissions for *all* users, it cannot be used to define fine-grained user permissions.  And removing the execute bit from commands in `/bin` is a sure way to mess up with your system.

Comment: @dr01 Thanks for your feedback. I will be sure to take it on board. I believe that the answer may not be appropriate for setting permissions for an individual user but could be helpful for setting permissions for users that are in a group. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.